# Issues Creating User in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to create user in openerp by python coding. I need to create a user for my website on odoo whenever a new user wants to signup. How can I achieve that?
I am doing the following:

```
def register_user(self, **post):
    cr, uid, context = request.cr, request.uid, request.context
    user_obj = request.registry.get('res.users')    
    user_info = {}
    user_info["name"] = post.get("name")
    user_info["email"] = post.get("email")
    user_info["password"] = post.get("password")

    user_created = user_obj.create(cr, uid, vals_user, context)

    return request.website.render("custom_module.custom_template")
```

However, I am getting an error here:
'You cannot create a new user from here. To create new user please go to configuration panel'

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I understood where I was going wrong. Putting user_info['login'] = True solved the purpose. However, I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it. I would still need some one to impart some understanding on this.

Comment: put your traceback here

Comment: @BomberMan: I have added trackback of a similar problem. Can you suggest some steps?

Answer (score 3):

The error refers to this code in `server/addons/mail/res_users.py`:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, data, context=None):
    # create default alias same as the login
    if not data.get('login', False):
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Invalid Action!'), _('You may not create a user. To create new users, you should use the "Settings > Users" menu.'))
```

So, this happens because you don't set `login` in param `data`. `login` is the username field of res.users

Answer (score 0):

self.env['res.users'].create({
            "name": 'Name',
            "email": 'Email',
            "login": 'Email'
        })